# R installation in Docker gets stuck in Geographic area

Tags: r, docker, ubuntu

I am installing R in docker using the following statement.

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        littler \
        r-cran-littler \
        r-base \
        r-base-dev \
        r-recommended \
        && echo 'options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org/"), download.file.method = "libcurl")' >> /etc/R/Rprofile.site \
        && echo 'source("/etc/R/Rprofile.site")' >> /etc/littler.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/install.r /usr/local/bin/install.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/install2.r /usr/local/bin/install2.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/installGithub.r /usr/local/bin/installGithub.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/testInstalled.r /usr/local/bin/testInstalled.r \
    && install.r docopt \
    && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

It ask a set of questions. In the first of all it gets stuck and I don't know why:

```
Configuring tzdata
------------------

Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.

  1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
  2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
  3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US
```

I answerthe following but nothing happens:

```
Geographic area: 8
```

The full dockerfile is:

```
#Main docke image
FROM ubuntu
#Los automatically thrown to the I/O strem and not buffered.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
#Set pythonpath (where python search code)
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.10.9
ARG AIRFLOW_USER_HOME=/usr/local/airflow

ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/"
#Allow airflow GPL dependencies
ENV SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes




#Install libraries and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip mysql-server vim
RUN apt-get install -y unzip wget
# Set the locale
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8


RUN set -ex \
    && buildDeps=' \
        freetds-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
        libsasl2-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        git \
    '&& apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get upgrade -yqq \
    && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
        $buildDeps \
        freetds-bin \
        build-essential \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        apt-utils \
        curl \
        rsync \
        netcat \
        locales \
        zip \
    && sed -i 's/^# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8$/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/g' /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    #&& useradd -ms /bin/bash -d ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME} airflow \
    && pip install -U setuptools wheel\
    && pip install pytz \
    && pip install pyOpenSSL \
    && pip install ndg-httpsclient \
    && pip install pyasn1 \
    && pip install apache-airflow[crypto,postgres,ssh,s3]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} \
    && pip install 'redis==3.2' \
    && if [ -n "${PYTHON_DEPS}" ]; then pip install ${PYTHON_DEPS}; fi \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -yqq $buildDeps \
    && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf \
        /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        /tmp/* \
        /var/tmp/* \
        /usr/share/man \
        /usr/share/doc \
        /usr/share/doc-base

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        littler \
        r-cran-littler \
        r-base \
        r-base-dev \
        r-recommended \
        && echo 'options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org/"), download.file.method = "libcurl")' >> /etc/R/Rprofile.site \
        && echo 'source("/etc/R/Rprofile.site")' >> /etc/littler.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/install.r /usr/local/bin/install.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/install2.r /usr/local/bin/install2.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/installGithub.r /usr/local/bin/installGithub.r \
    && ln -s /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/testInstalled.r /usr/local/bin/testInstalled.r \
    && install.r docopt \
    && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR "/"
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
#arg to entrypoint
CMD ["webserver"]
```

Answer (score 28):

It's a standard Debian feature that it wants that information. You can force an override in any scripted installation by turning off interactive mode.  In a Dockerfile that works via the `ENV` keyword:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
```

I do use this in a few Dockerfiles of the Rocker Project:

```
edd@rob:~$ grep DEBIAN git/rocker/*/Dockerfile git/rocker/*/*/Dockerfile 
git/rocker/r-devel/Dockerfile:ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
git/rocker/r-apt/bionic/Dockerfile:ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
git/rocker/r-apt/cosmic/Dockerfile:ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
git/rocker/r-apt/disco/Dockerfile:ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
git/rocker/r-bspm/bionic/Dockerfile:#ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
git/rocker/r-bspm/focal/Dockerfile:#ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
git/rocker/r-bspm/testing/Dockerfile:#ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
git/rocker/r-rspm/bionic/Dockerfile:ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
git/rocker/r-rspm/focal/Dockerfile:ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
git/rocker/r-ubuntu/bionic/Dockerfile:ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
git/rocker/r-ubuntu/focal/Dockerfile:ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
edd@rob:~$
```

BTW looks like the Dockerfile in your question is a straight-up copy of mine. Nice to see it being used, might be even nicer if you put a comment in about where you sourced it from ...

Comment: make sure to provide after `FROM ubuntu:22.04`

Comment: Note that setting DEBIAN_FRONTEND to noninteractive will make the install use the default answer to all interactive questions. This might not be the behavior you want. I prefer setting the time zone explicitly.

Ref.: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/explain-debian_frontend-apt-get-variable-for-ubuntu-debian/

Answer (score 22):

Setting timezone configs manually worked for me:

```
ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Comment: This works like a charm.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/504043/how-to-list-timezones-known-to-the-system
Adding this

Comment: I prefer this solution compared to setting DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive. I don't like having to rely on the default choices in noninteractive mode. Setting the time zone like this is more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

worked here too! I was with this issue, trying to install cmake in ubuntu20.04 in docker!

Comment: Please don't write a new answer confirming an existing answer; upvote the working answer instead.

Comment: This answer is potentially better, as it uses the non-persistent ARG clause, rather than ENV.