# Apptainer build gets stuck at "Geographic area" selection

Tags: apt, singularity-container, apptainer

I tried to build an apptainer image from the following definition file:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: pytorch/pytorch:2.0.1-cuda11.7-cudnn8-devel

%files
    ./requirements.txt /src/requirements.txt

%post
    apt -y update
    apt -y install git libxml2-dev

%runscript
    $@
```

But the build process prompts for entering the geographic area and then gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62299928/r-installation-in-docker-gets-stuck-in-geographic-area), adding

```
TZ=Europe/Berlin
ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

at the beginning of the %post section did the trick for me.

Final definition file:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: pytorch/pytorch:2.0.1-cuda11.7-cudnn8-devel

%files
    ./requirements.txt /src/requirements.txt

%post
    TZ=Europe/Berlin
    ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
    

    apt -y update
    apt -y install git libxml2-dev

%runscript
    $@
```